# Differentiating a sympy function with an unknown number of variables

Tags: python, function, sympy

let's assume I have a script that creates a vector v with a certain number of elements x1, x2, x3, etc (each element is a sympy symbol).

```
import sympy as sp

# generated by script, so the number of symbols/length of v is always different:
sp.var("x1,x2,x3,x4,...")
v = sp.Matrix([x1,x2,x3,x4,...])

g = sp.Function("g")
```

I want g to be a function of x1,x2,x3,..., so g(x1,x2,x3,x4, ...) in order to differentiate it.

```
g.diff(x1) # does not work
g(x1,x2,x3).diff(x1) # works, but the number of variables varies
```

Any idea how I can solve this problem?

Edit: I should mention that I did quite some research. I hope I did not miss anything obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the *star expressions*

```
In [13]: g(*v)
Out[13]: g(x1, x2, x3, x4)

In [14]: g(*v).diff(x1)
Out[14]: Derivative(g(x1, x2, x3, x4), x1)
```